# Send MIDI to Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth using sendmidi

Tags: cmd, send, midi

I'm trying to send a midi note to Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth using [sendmidi](https://github.com/gbevin/SendMIDI/releases)

```
sendmidi dev Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth channel 1 on 60 64
```

but I don't get any sound,
it's sending to the other midi devices and I get sound, by `sendmidi list` I get a list of devices.

Comment: There is no MIDI Mapper in the list but ```sendmidi dev MIDI Mapper channel 1 on 60 64``` did it

Comment: The docs always `"quote"` device names with spaces.

Comment: Thanks that's what it was ```sendmidi dev "Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth" pc 17 channel 1 on 60 90 clock 80```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ensure that the device name is interpreted as a single parameter, you have to quote it:

```
sendmidi dev "Microsoft GS Wavetable Synth" pc 17 channel 1 on 60 90
```